# Where does this line come from?

Tags: pgfplots

I'm really new to LaTeX (like yesterday new), and also really new to fractional equations (ninth grade). When I tried to plot one in LaTeX using pgfplots I got this result:

[image: fractional equation with a line x=0]

However, when I plot it in Desmos and some other software, the line of `x=0` disappears:

[image: fractional equation without that line]

What is the reason for this? Is it just a thing that pgfplots does, and is it mathematically correct to plot it? And how would I go about fixing it if it's wrong?

Here is my code btw:

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-10, xmax=10, ymin=-10, ymax=10,
    axis lines = middle,
    xlabel = \(x\),
    ylabel = {\(f(x)\)},
    grid = both,
    axis equal
]
\addplot [
    domain=-15:15, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
]
{-3+(12/x)};
\addlegendentry{\(-3+\frac{12}{x}\)}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: always show a small, but complete example (beginning with \documentclass). That makes it much easier to test your issue.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is due to the way how PGFplots plots functions: continuously. You can add `unbounded coords=jump, x filter/.expression={x==0 ? nan : x}` to the options of the `axis` environment to enable skipping for *x* = 0. (Actually, you only need to add `x filter` for certain values of `samples`. You should probably rather use `samples=101` which makes `x filter` uncessary.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PGFplots usually plots a continuous line which results from connecting a list of coordinates that are calculated using the given function. The amount of coordinates can be specified using the `samples` option, which means that if you state `samples=4`, you will get four coordinates that are then connected to a (zig-zag/angular) line. The more samples/coordinates, the smoother the plotted line will get.

The function you show, however, is non-continuous. For non-continuous functions, you should add the option `unbounded coords=jump` to the `axis` environment to enable jumping (that is, temporarily stopping drawing) over coordinates for which PGFplots calculates `NaN` (not a number), which is the case, for example, for a division by 0.

Now, if you set the number of `samples` in such a way that it happens that PGFplots does not calculate the coordinate exactly at *x* = 0, jumping over NaN values won't help you much, because in the list of coordinates calculated by PGFplots no coordinate with an NaN value exists. Therefore, you should make sure that your sample size is such that one of the values exactly hits *x* = 0, which would be the case for any odd number in the case of your function. So, for example, 101 would do, but 100 does not.

The following, therefore, will give the desired output without the vertical line:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-10, xmax=10, ymin=-10, ymax=10,
    axis lines=middle,
    xlabel={\(x\)},
    ylabel={\(f(x)\)},
    grid=both,
    axis equal
]
\addplot [
    domain=-15:15, 
    samples=101, 
    color=red,
    unbounded coords=jump,
] {-3+(12/x)};
\addlegendentry{\(-3+\frac{12}{x}\)}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice answer, but I would say that `samples=4` wpuld give 4 pairs of coordinates, not 3, doesn't it?

Comment: @Jhor You are right! I corrected this.

Comment: Would there be a way to make this happen for `samples=100`?  If I were to try graphing `1/(x-1)`, it'd be a bit complicated to figure out how many samples I would need in order to have x=1 be among the sample points.

Comment: @Teepeemm You could always split the plot, I think, so that one part goes up to 0.99 and the second starts at 1.01 or something like this.